# What should be the redirect URL for an API request?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, heroku, heroku-cli

I started recently working on API's and few API providers are not requesting redirect URL while some others are requesting. I have written an algorithmic strategy for trading using python. When I requested for API to Fyers(stockbroker), the team said me to provide a redirect URL. what is a redirect URL? and how to create it?

[image]

I have attached image for reference. In the above image, there is a text box for Redirect URL. Can you please explain what exactly is Redirect URL and how to create one for calling API for authentication if my code is on heroku?

Comment: Hi -- welcome to stackoverflow! Where have you tried looking so far? Please provide more detail around the API usage with perhaps an example; the more clear detail you present in the question, the better an answer you will get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Redirect URL is required by the [oAuth workflow](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/redirect-uris/): basically the authorisation server will redirect the user back to the URL registered as "Redirect URL" including an authorization code or a token.

If you register a URL like `https://myapp.herokuapp.com` you will be redirected to

```
https://myapp.herokuapp.com?access_code=XXX&app_id=YYY
```

The Redirect URL needs to be a valid accessible page: if the process is manual you just copy the `access_code` from the browser and use it accordingly.
If it is an application you need to receive the redirect above (the URL is basically your app), fetch the required information (parameters) and implement your logic.

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity you can use localhost as your redirect url. Something like http://localhost:4004/
You can change the port number (4004) if you want.

Answer (score 0):

### Default Fyers Redirect URL for Testing

- Use the default url from fyers

  ```
  https://trade.fyers.in/api-login/redirect-uri/index.html
  ```
- Copy the auth key value
- Use it in your python app in the second run
- You can also use google collab, to run part of code only (authentication) without restarting the whole project